# MySQL Hibernate "Already closed" ERROR after a day without use

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, mule

This is a **Hibernate** / **Mule** application that has a **MySQL** connection.

By the moment that the application is started the requests are done just fine. But after some time, not sure if 12 to 15 hours **without requests**, the first request after this time is thrown `ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Already closed.`. When the second request is done, it work just fine.

**Connection configuration**

```
    <!-- XYZ -->
    <bean name="dataSourceXYZ" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" /> 
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://database:3306/xyz_base?serverTimezone=UTC&amp;verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=false&amp;requireSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactoryXYZ"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceXYZ" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="XYZPU" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.domain.xyz.entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" /> 
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>                    
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57InnoDBDialect</prop>              
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnect">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</prop>
            <prop key="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</prop>    
         </props>
      </property>      

    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerXYZ"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryXYZ" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManagerXYZ" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactoryXYZ" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerXYZ" />
```

**Complete error exception**

```
2020-05-05 11:37:38,331 [[mule_intra].sharedHttpListenerConfig.worker.09] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2020-05-05 11:37:38,331 [[mule_intra].sharedHttpListenerConfig.worker.09] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Already closed.
2020-05-05 11:37:38,354 [[mule_intra].sharedHttpListenerConfig.worker.09] ERROR org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy -
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke com.domain.api.service.ColService@6dcf91b3.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /get:\/col:api-config/processors/0 @ rh:api.xml:173 (Invoke)
Element XML           : <invoke object-ref="colService" method="findAll" methodArguments="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params']" doc:name="Invoke"></invoke>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Pipe quebrado
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.SimplePacketSender.send(SimplePacketSender.java:55)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TimeTrackingPacketSender.send(TimeTrackingPacketSender.java:50)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.send(NativeProtocol.java:578)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendCommand(NativeProtocol.java:648)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryPacket(NativeProtocol.java:980)
        at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.sendQueryString(NativeProtocol.java:915)
        at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:1182)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2057)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:371)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:328)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72)
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:166)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy130.findAll(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.mule.processor.InvokerMessageProcessor.process(InvokerMessageProcessor.java:166)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:138)
        at org.mule.construct.Flow$2.process(Flow.java:133)
        at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
        at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
        at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
        at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:60)
        at org.mule.execution.ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(ErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
        at org.mule.construct.Flow.process(Flow.java:132)
        at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processBlockingRequest(AbstractRouter.java:87)
        at org.mule.module.apikit.AbstractRouter.processBlocking(AbstractRouter.java:77)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
        at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
        at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
        at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:232)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:73)
        at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:72)
        at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:59)
        at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
        at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
        at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
        at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
        at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
        at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
        at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
        at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
        at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
        at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
        at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
        at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
        at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
        at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
        at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:58)
        at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35)
        at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
        at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
        at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:133)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
        at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

********************************************************************************
```

Comment: You should enable the Java property mule.verbose.exceptions=true for a really complete stacktrace.

Comment: Ok, I will update de question with the "verbose" version of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that the connection is being closed by the database or a firewall somewhere in the middle.

Some database pools allow configuration of maximum time to live connection settings. The timeout value should be set to a value smaller than the value set for the closing component. For example, if idle connections are closed after 12 hours, you could set it in the pool as 11 hours.

[DBCP 1.4 Documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)

**The solution for DBCP 1.x**

Include these properties:

```
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />
```

This will check / restore the connection every minute.

As a side-note, DBCP 1.x is really old. You should consider moving to a newer 2.x release or use a different library.

Comment: I using JPA, I will try to find some property that do the same thing `maxConnLifetimeMillis` do for DBCP

Comment: Your JPA configuration reference the DBCP pool datasource: `<bean name="dataSourceXYZ" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">`. You can set this property at the pool.

Comment: Ow thank you, my mistake. I was looking at my database server variables and `wait_timeout = 28800 (8 hours)`. The mysql description for *wait_timeout* is _The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it._. So looking into DBCP docs what do you thing about the `removeAbandonedTimeout` instead of `maxConnLifetimeMillis`? Because I think `maxConnLifetimeMillis` doesn´t consider iddle time. Either way I think these are the ways for the solution.

Comment: `removeAbandoned*` configurations in DBCP deal with connections that are not returned to the pool after a long time, and don't appear to be in use. That is probably caused by a problem in the logic, or some other library. If you have those then you have a different problem. I would use still use `maxConnLifetimeMillis`, but I would complement it with `validationQuery` and the `testWhileIdle` configurations, to be sure that idle connections *in* the pool are still valid. Using a validation query is a good practice. Having said that most or all these configurations can be used together.

Comment: I edited your answer to add the properties that resolved my problem but the edit was refused. The properties were:<property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000" />
     <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
     <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't had time to review it yet.